# Access 2 Hosts from Internet on same subnet

Tags: networking, routing, router, redirection, dmz

Hi I  have 2 raspberry PI in my network. And I want both of them accessibles from the internet. Right now I have a DMZ from you can access one with  NO-IP setup:

***www.blabla.no-ip.org ----->DMZ REDIRECTION ON MY ROUTER----->192.168.1.XX Static Address.***

What I want to do is:

***www.blabla.no-ip.org ----->ROUTING OF ANY KIND----->192.168.1.XX Static Address
www.talktalk.no-ip.org ----->ROUTING OF ANY KIND----->192.168.1.XY Static Address***

Since each of host are running services with webinterfaces I usually access them from remote machines.

Right now doing a SSH dynamic port forwarding (socks proxy). But its just a temporary fix up.

I cant get to think of any kind of solution for this (wich Im sure its easy to do).

**NOTE:
This setup is for my home network, I have a generic router ASL-26555 AMPER.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found out I can make virtual servers or virtual aplications on some routers.

Mine was a Virtual Server. I Only had to specify the ongoing IP with a specific port to be routed to another IP on another port.